# Handler.postDelayed not called when mobilephone in standby mode

Tags: java, android, handler

I'm trying to write a simple app that should mute my mobile phone for a given time. It's my first Android app, but after many hours of reading I think it is nearly completed. But it still has one problem that I can not fix.

I'm using a activity to display the GUI. It has Buttons to set the start and end time, and everything else needed. When the user has entered all the parameters, they are passed to a service. This service uses a handler object, to register 2 callbacks (with Handler.postDelayed). One for start Mute and one for End Mute (in SetMuteIntervall).
The first tests seemed to work, but if I try to mute it for like 30 minutes, it never unmutes. I think it has something to do with the fact, that the mobilephone is or was in standby mode. I also tried to use Handler.postAt() but that didn't work either (and time relative to uptime was somewhat confusing).

So, what should I do to guarantee, that my callbacks are called, regardless whether the phone is in standby or not?

Here's the source of my program:

http://pastebin.com/XAgCeAq9

http://pastebin.com/33nepFV5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use AlarmManager for planning some actions in future. AlarmManager is not standby-mode-dependend and will fire even if device is sleeping.

Your thread are actually stopped then the phone is in stand by mode. If you still want to use thread you can use WakeLock to prevent CPU from going to stand by mode (but still to switch screen off) but this is not the best way in your case.